# Node definition for lib functions

Tags: ocaml

In the map.ml lib file, the function height is defined as follows:

```
let height = function
    Empty -> 0
  | Node(_,_,_,_,h) -> h
```

My question is: *where is Node() actually defined?*

I have searched the entire set of ocaml source files and fond nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the OCaml 4.05.0 source for `map.ml` I see this:

```
type 'a t =
    Empty
  | Node of 'a t * key * 'a * 'a t * int

let height = function
    Empty -> 0
  | Node(_,_,_,_,h) -> h
```

The definition is immediately before the `height` function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very new to ocaml syntax therefore I was searching for "Node =" instead of "Node of". I actually found what I was looking for in another file and it was completely wrong lol

Comment: Cool, glad to help. If you're new to OCaml it might be better to start with something simpler than the standard library implementation :-) A few smaller examples might get you going faster.